# Point lights, not reflecting on ocean?

Tags: lighting, ocean-simulation, reflection

I have an ocean at night and would like to put lights shining across the waves or on them etc, but all lights work fine except the "point" lights that I am trying to use.

Why would only point lights have I think zero effect on ocean surface and others are fine, but the point lights do shine on all other surfaces?

Is it an ocean modifier issue?

Comment: try spheres with emission, and disable the spheres for the render.

Comment: its for an across the waves light source, I don't want to have to trail lots of spheres, or I might as well use spot lights.

Comment: I hope someone can answer your question, I'm curious now :)

Comment: could you please share your file?

Comment: too large to share/project, and it is not really a big ask. and I haven't shared a file on blender before and don't know how to "pack_it" if it needs packing etc?